# Why is this If/Elif loop so slow?

Tags: python-3.x, if-statement

Can anyone tell me why this code is so slow? Is there any way I can speed it up?
Basically, I'm making a Pandas dataframe (network) by following the pseudocode:

1. Make empty dataframe (a network for networkx)
2. Define lists of the objects I'm interested in (list of ChampionsA
   and list of  ChampionsB). These are the nodes.
3. For all combinations of championsA and championsB, do the following:
4. Count how many times you see championA and championB together, in
   that order (AB). This is a directed edge between A and B.
5. Count how many times you see championB and championA together, in
   that order (BA). This is a directed edge between B and A.
6. Assign weights to these directed edges by doing the following:
7. If directed edges A->B and B->A both exist, apply the following
   formula to the edge weights.
8. If A->B exists and B->A doesn't, then assign another formula for
   edge weight.
9. If B->A exists and A->B doesn't, then assign another formula for
   edge weight.
10. Put these weights into the dataframe network.

Code:

```
    network = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Champion A','Champion B', 'Weight'])
    championsA = listA
    championsB = listB

    for champb in championsB:
        for champa in championsA:

           AB = tally.loc[tally['Champion B'] == champb].loc[tally['Champion A'] == champa]
           BA = tally.loc[tally['Champion A'] == champb].loc[tally['Champion B'] == champa]

                if len(AB) == 1 and len(BA) == 1:
                    wA = AB['Weight'].iloc[0]
                    wB = BA['Weight'].iloc[0]
                    AB['Weight'] = somenumber
                    BA['Weight'] = somenumber
                elif len(AB) == 1 and len(BA) == 0: 
                    AB['Weight'] = someothernumber
                elif len(AB) == 0 and len(BA) == 1: 
                    BA['Weight'] = someothernumber
                network = pd.concat([network,AB])
                network = pd.concat([network,BA])
```

Comment: On a large dataset, it takes over an hour to generate my dataframe network. And I have over 40 datasets to run.....

Comment: What is the length of listA and listB? you basically are running the for loops len(listA) * len(listB) times. Then for everytime, you are running the if-else statement

Comment: len(listA) about the same as len(listB) which is something like 145. No way to shorten it, unfortunately.

Comment: Just to note, building off of the comment of @Dinesh.hmn, your code will have a performance with a big Oh notation of O(n^2), meaning the larger the sizes of listA and listB grow to infinity, the performance will suffer at a quadratic rate. The comparisons and assignments within the loops are linear and shouldn't really impact performance from what I see.

Comment: T^T
That being said, I guess it really is the only way to calculate all the edges in a network, assuming directed edges can go in both directions simultaneously. It's always going to be a quadratic algorithm?